# Fancybox and mcustomscrollbar ipad issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, fancybox

I am using Fancybox and mcustomscrollbar together. i want to open my project in fancybox and it works fine in Computer but in ipad i have to maintain pressed and then it open the contextual menu and after select open it open the fancybox. can you please explain what i have to do to open fancybox with just a single touch on project image.

Url:- http://studioplusarch.com/gsc/

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I read this Probleme:
"If I open the last
page directly the mcustomscrollbar work ok, but if that page is open
with the fancybox, then the mcustomscrollbarr doesn´t work."

My answer is: The class, for example 'fancy-content' where you hide the fancy content before you load with the fancybox link, don't make it "display: none", do as in the example below:

```
/* element bifore load */ .fancy-content{ display: block; /*not none*/ height: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; } /*  element after load in fancybox inner */ .fancybox-inner .fancy-content{ height: auto; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Hello! I was thinking, that it could have displaying problem on touch. When your content is "display none" in css, before you load it with fancybox, the "mcustomscrollbar" is interpreting the content width and height strange, because "mcustomscrollbar" doesn't now the content width and height after loading with fancybox. And in this case, you can try like in the example above. :-)

Comment: And if this doesn't work, here are some useful links: 1. http://benhowdle.im/touche/ 2. http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html Maybe you can find this useful for you! And put a condition for window width or user agent!

Comment: ...hire you can switch the click event to touch event!